# Match all variants of short form of example (e.g.) in python regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

I want to identify all variants of a short form of example e.g and replace it with space.
The regex I tried is given below. It matches e.g but doesn't match the other variants. What am I doing wrong?

```
(?:^|\s)([e]\.[g](\.)?)(?=\s|$)
```

The data input is

```
e.g E.g E.G. e.g.
```

The regex should match all of these variants.

The regex can be tried at  - https://regex101.com/r/oFQxYJ/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is already working if you use `re.IGNORECASE`, for example:

```
import re
pat = "(?:^|\s)([e]\.[g](\.)?)(?=\s|$)"    # unchanged from question
data = "e.g E.g E.G. e.g."
regex = re.compile(pat, re.IGNORECASE)     # note the IGNORECASE
print(regex.findall(data))
```

gives

```
[('e.g', ''), ('E.g', ''), ('E.G.', '.'), ('e.g.', '.')]
```

Or if you do not want to use `re.IGNORECASE`, then include the upper case variants in the character classes:

```
import re
pat = "(?:^|\s)([eE]\.[gG](\.)?)(?=\s|$)"   # note the [eE] and [gG] here
data = "e.g E.g E.G. e.g."
regex = re.compile(pat)
print(regex.findall(data))
```

(same output as above).

But by default `[e]` will be a case-sensitive match (and in this case the `[` ... `]` do not make any difference because it means match any of the characters inside the square brackets, but there is only one).

Then to replace with space, use `sub`.  This will replace *all* the matches in the line, so is equivalent to `findall`.  For example:

```
import re
pat = "(?:^|\s)([eE]\.[gG](\.)?)(?=\s|$)"
data2 = "test e.g test E.g test E.G. test e.g. test"
regex = re.compile(pat)
print(regex.sub(" ", data2))    # <== using sub
```

gives

```
test  test  test  test  test
```

Comment: In regex101, it is not showing match to any variant apart from the first one though i is used for case insensitive match. That confused me. Let me check again. Thanks

Comment: @Sid You may need "global" on that website. Here I am using `findall`.

Comment: @alaiwi, yup that was the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the code for search and replace in one regex, but to search:

```
([eE]\.[gG]\.{0,1})
```

a bit unprecise, or the rolled out version

((e.g)|(E.g)|(E.G.)|(e.g.))

Comment: ((e\.g)|(E\.g)|(E\.G\.)|(e\.g\.))
 I meant